# Self-contained database?

Tags: desktop-application, relational-database

Is there a way to distribute a (smallish) self-contained relational database along with an Windows application that does not require users to install additional dependencies such as MS Access, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, etc.? Only the application will be accessing the database - not users directly.

Comment: Include your app language SVP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033CFB76-5382-44FB-BC7E-B3C8174832E2)

[SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx)

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

to name just a few.

Comment: Went with SQL Server Compact Edition. Having to write scripts to perform all tasks seemed like kind of a pain to me, so I created a normal SQL Server database to perform all modifications upon, and now port it to Compact Edition using a third-party tool whenever I need to. Works pretty well.

Comment: @posfan12: Cool. What's the name of the third party tool?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Compact Edition 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would embed SQLite in my application.  There's various ways to do this depending on the language your are using.